# Invalid JSON primitive when sending string with numbers and characters

Tags: json, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to send a string through via the .ajax method on a button click.

If I set reportIdStr to "123" it will work. If I set it to "123ccc" I get the following:

"Invalid JSON primitive: 123ccc.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer"

Here is my code, I know it is something silly, I am not familiar with JSON....

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "AJAX_test.aspx/ProcessIt",
data: '{reportIdStr: '+idStr+' }',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI

This line should have been formatted correctly:

```
data: "{'reportIdStr':'" +idStr+ "' }",
```

Solved the issue.